# В OpenFire не работает плагин Monitoring Service

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

[image: web]
Ubuntu server 14.04 и Openfire 4.0.3.
Из куска лога видно что просит таблицу. Нужно ли вручную создать таблицы и если создавать то с какими параметрами?

2016.12.14 10:02:25 org.jivesoftware.openfire.reporting.stats.RrdSqlBackend - Error while accessing information in database: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'openfire.ofRRDs' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Нашел такой выход:

1. Установил monitoring service 1.5.8;
2. Остановил OpenFire - sudo service openfire stop;
3. Удалил содержимое из папки monitoring, на Ubuntu это /usr/share/openfire/~plugins/monitoring;
4. Скопировал в эту папку содержимое архива [monitoring_1.4.2.zip](https://community.igniterealtime.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/254071-28452/monitoring_1.4.2.zip);
5. Запустил OpenFire - sudo service openfire start.